# Regex: Select lines that do not contain the tag

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I don't know why is not working this regex.

Suppose I have this 2 lines:

```
1. A Refined Form Of Exercising power</a></h1></td>

2. A Refined Form Of Exercising power</h1></td>
```

I want to select those lines that do not contain the tag `</a>` , that means the search result will only display the second line.

I made a regex, but is not working:

`(?:(?!<\/a>)).*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work: `^((?!<\/a>).)*$`

Comment: Also, if I want to select those lines that do not contain specific three tags, then the regex will be:  `^((?!<\/a><\/h1><\/td>).)*$`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [Tempered Greedy Token](https://rucode1111.blogspot.com/2015/05/regex-tempered-greedy-token-what-is.html) but you've made a typo, the dot `.` must be **inside** the non capture group (and there're no needs to escape the slash that is **not** a special character for regex):

```
(?:(?!</a>).)*
#   here __^
```

If you want to exclude more than one expression, you have to use alternatives:

```
(?:(?!</a>|</h1>|</td>).)*
```

OR

```
(?:(?!</(?:a|h1|td)>).)*
```

OR

```
(?:(?!</a>)(?!</h1>)(?!</td>).)*
```